# Сохранение результата в js-скрипте

Tags: javascript

Есть игра на js скрипте, как сделать, чтобы можно было сохранять набранный результат, и продолжить на том месте, где остановился? Желательно сохранять в cookies, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: "Немедленно займитесь делом"! (с), а не игрушками занимайтесь противными.

Comment: @vlasov0001, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Answer (score 2):

Если базы данных нет, используйте localStorage (HTML5):

```
localStorage.setItem('name', value); // сохранение

value = localStorage.getItem('name') // восстановление
```

Comment: А можно описание куда это вставить...

Answer (score 0):

Взято из Macromedia Dreamveawer и переведены комменты:

```
// Пример:
// alert( readCookie("myCookie") );
function readCookie(name)
{
  var cookieValue = "";
  var search = name + "=";
  if(document.cookie.length > 0)
  { 
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search);
    if (offset != -1)
    { 
      offset += search.length;
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
      if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
      cookieValue = unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
    }
  }
  else{return null;}
  return cookieValue;
}
// Пример:
// writeCookie("myCookie", "my name", 24);
// Записывает строку "my name" в cookie "myCookie" который истекает через 24 часа.
function writeCookie(name, value, hours)
{
  var expire = "";
  if(hours != null)
  {
    expire = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + hours * 3600000);
    expire = "; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expire;
}
```